# Detect that android app has been updated

Tags: android, events, google-play, broadcast

I need to find out a way to detect that my app has been updated from google play. 
After the update I want to run some functions that should only be runned once (and only after update).

Are there any events or broadcasts sent after google play has updated an app?

Or is there another way to find out?

Comment: at startup, load the last saved version from a sharedpref, compare it with current version, do your things, then save the current version in shared prefs

Comment: or you can use the update broadcast, that's `PACKAGE_REPLACED` (but that is called when the app is updated, not when the app is used after an update)

Comment: @njzk2 what if the user edits the version save in sharedpref? , your app will go crazy, especially when they put in strange digits, that's just btw..

Comment: @Elltz: the user can't do that unless you provide them with a ui to do so... (which would be quite a silly thing to do)

Comment: I think I am going for the sharedpref alternativ. Thanks!